ER diagram Verification
An airplane company needs a database. Its desired design is described
below.

For every airplane owned by the company the system needs to store its
registration number, which is unique for every airplane.
Each airplane is associated with exactly one type.
A type is identified by its name. In addition, for every type we store its
size.
Every airplane is based at a specific airport which should be stored in
the system.
For each airport we want to store its ID and its capacity. In addition we
want to store the neighbouring airports to it (an airport can neighbour
more than one airport).

below is my design do you think so its valid?


i would add a table airport , Neighbors that link to airport, else you can save multiple Neighbors, your schema doesn't allow multiple neighnors

@nbk I think so it will enable since it has many to many relationship ?

yes you need a n:m relationship as multiple airports can neighbours to identical airports
